# Filtering a CSV file column and then export it to excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a huge dataset in a csv file and want to filter one of the columns if they are equal to 334 and then export all the dataset into a excel file! when the file is filtered it can be used in a excel file. so far I could manage to write this code but I do not know how to filter the column and then export all into a excel file.

```
import itertools
import csv   
from itertools import islice

with open("eee.csv", 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    for row in itertools.islice(reader, 100):
         print (row)
```

Comment: Is the 334th column or any value is 334 ? It should be clearer. Or you can open the file in excel, and get the job done there.

Comment: 334 is a value in one of the columns. since its like 10 million rows i need to filter it here and then  go to excel so it can open it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('eee.csv', header=0)

df = df[df['column_name'].map(lambda x: x == 334)]

df.to_csv('eee.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is great at these things, but if you want to do same without...

```
import itertools
import csv   
from itertools import islice

column_nbr = 3
keep = []

with open("eee.csv", 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    for row in itertools.islice(reader, 100):
        print (row)
        cmp = row[column_nbr]
        if cmp == 334:
            keep.append(row)

with open('filtered.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(keep)
```

This will only work reasonably well as long as the keep list is not too long.
In case the keep list is long, you could make keep a file instead and append to that file.

There is another way as well, you could just pipe the output of the printing to a file.
Something like:

```
python the_read_script_with_print.py > filtered_rows.txt
```

The change in the code above is just forget the keep list as well as the writing of results to file, and just do the `print(row)` in the if-statement, no need to save the rows in memory, the piping will put them in a text file directly.

At last, excel will open csv just fine (although local settings could put you in the spot where you have to slit columns yourself)

Or not using python at all is another approach for a question like this...

On Windows in cmd.exe: `FINDSTR /C:",334," eee.csv > filtered_rows.txt`

On Linux: see answer from caot

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
cat eee.csv | grep ,334, > filtered_rows.txt
```

Comment: definetly the way to go if on Linux

finally triggered me as windows user to find a windows way of doing it...

`FINDSTR /C:",334," eee.csv > filtered_rows.txt`

should do it as well

Comment: So, I am a very new Python user. Using this syntax cat... just give me to the syntax error, can you please elaborate a bit for me about the sytanx and what it does exactly? should I just put it after the Print?

Comment: hm, for these 2 things you don't use python at all, it's directly in bash (cat/grep) for Linux or commandprompt for windows (FINDSTR)

Comment: @ahed87 windows user can install https://www.cygwin.com/ that a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.

Comment: very true, but also not always that everyone have that freedom on the computers they are using...